# Omit dollar placeholder in Spring @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I would like to use Spring Boot configuration in my application, however, there's one thing I don't like about it. My app is in early development phase and property keys are likely to change. Usually, I use public static String constants for property names, so whenever a key changes, I only have to change it in one place. With that being said, I would have to configure my application like this:

```
@Value("${" + AppConstants.SOME_STRING_PROPERTY + "}")
private String someProperty;
```

Is there any 'cleaner' way to achieve that, possibly without using `${}` placeholder all the time?

Comment: Ideally values change, not keys. But okay, if that's the situation. I don't know personally how to achieve this, but I know that Intellij can refactor this too, so you will change only at one place.

Comment: As I said, key changes are result of design changes at this stage of work. Also, having one class with property keys serves as a developer documentation - it's much esasier to find all configuration options this way than searching for all @Value annotation occurences. I would also like to avoid manually refactoring with IDE, as that's why I'm using tools like Spring in the first place.

Comment: Unless you are willing to write your own annotation and its post processor, you can not omit `${}`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`@ConfigurationProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) feature. You can import the whole configuration file into java POJO without any dollar signs. You can also validate configuration with validation annotations and you get type safety out of the box.